# WCF WebInvoke which can accept content-type: text/plain?

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm writing a WCF REST service to receive AWS SNS Notification Message with my WCF REST Service.

However, WCF REST only supports XML and JSON, but because of legacy reasons Amazon SNS posts their notifications with the `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` header, according to the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
// ...

{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  // ...
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&..."
}
```

When I call my service with this "text/plain" content type like Amazon, there is an error which says:

> Request Error.
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The  expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details.

My current code:

```
public interface MyServiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/AmazonIPChanges")]
    Task AmazonIPChanges(SNSNotificationMessage data);
}

[DataContract]
public class SNSNotificationMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    // ...
    [DataMember]
    public string UnsubscribeURL { get; set; }
}
```

The DataContract maps to the Amazon SNS message. This code is working when I perform a POST with content-type "application/json", but how can I let it accept Amazon's text/plain content-type?

Comment: It makes no sense to want to post data in plaintext to a web service, so the error is correct. What does your request look like, exactly?

Comment: you must be misunderstood. AWS SNS is a notification service. i'm not sending a message. AWS is sending it. I'm just trying to get this input.

Comment: What makes you think SNS posts in plaintext? Their documentation indicates JSON.

Comment: I think you didn't read the document entirely. There is a place which says what does notification message contain. You can see there, header's content type plaintext but body is a json content. also you can search and see it's a kind of bug but Amazon couldn't change it because they don't want to affect current customer implementations. and also again i parsed the packet and saw what it contains

Comment: Then again, show such a notification.

Comment: Yes, it's exacly like what Amazon Documentation says. You can see the message from there. I linked the documentation address in the first sentence, you probably saw that before.

Comment: I've reformatted your question a bit to include all relevant details from the AWS documentation.

Comment: I saw that your way is much more clear way to say the problem and i was trying to achieve WebContentTypeMapper customization. Your answer and examples are very good. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I should have been more clear in my comments about what exactly should be in your question. Happy to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this, as the error message indicates, by creating and applying a custom `WebContentTypeMapper`. It should look like this:

```
namespace StackOverflow36216464
{
    public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            switch (contentType.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "text/plain":
                case "application/json":
                    return WebContentFormat.Json;
                case "application/xml":
                    return WebContentFormat.Xml;
                default:
                    return WebContentFormat.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one interprets the content-type of the request, and returns the appropriate `WebContentFormat` enum member.

You can then apply it to your service in the form of a custom binding:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="textPlainToApplicationJson">
                <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="StackOverflow36216464.RawContentTypeMapper, StackOverflow36216464, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="debugServiceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service
          name="StackOverflow36216464.Service1"
          behaviorConfiguration="debugServiceBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:65393/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  contract="StackOverflow36216464.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restEndpointBehavior"
                  bindingConfiguration="textPlainToApplicationJson"/>        
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The relevant part being the `<customBinding>` element, where the custom mapper is configured, and the `servcices/service/endpoint/bindingConfiguration` attribute where it is applied.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem with .net core web api, would you be able to help out with that? Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519950/net-core-1-0-web-api-processing-request-body-as-json-when-content-type-is-text or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515635/parsing-aws-sns-notification-in-net-core-1-0

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Amazon SNS now supports custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the feature announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

As you can see, you basically need to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, `application/xml`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

Here's a sample `DeliveryPolicy` for reference:

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!