# Parsing AWS SNS notification in .net core 1.0

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sns

I have a VisualStudio17 serverless application project and am using .net core Web Api.

I want to confirm my SNS subscription, but I have a problem that AWS sends the POST request with header `content-type` set to `text/plain; charset=UTF-8` while body is JSON.

Here's an example request from their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: Notification
x-amz-sns-message-id: da41e39f-ea4d-435a-b922-c6aae3915ebe
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic
x-amz-sns-subscription-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:2bcfbf39-05c3-41de-beaa-fcfcc21c8f55
Content-Length: 761
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: ec2-50-17-44-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent

{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "da41e39f-ea4d-435a-b922-c6aae3915ebe",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Subject" : "test",
  "Message" : "test message",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-04-25T21:49:25.719Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "EXAMPLElDMXvB8r9R83tGoNn0ecwd5UjllzsvSvbItzfaMpN2nk5HVSw7XnOn/49IkxDKz8YrlH2qJXj2iZB0Zo2O71c4qQk1fMUDi3LGpij7RCW7AW9vYYsSqIKRnFS94ilu7NFhUzLiieYr4BKHpdTmdD6c0esKEYBpabxDSc=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:2bcfbf39-05c3-41de-beaa-fcfcc21c8f55"
}
```

Content-type: text, body JSON. This makes it parsing quite difficult, and a simple

`public void Post([FromBody] string t) // or dynamic t for the matter`

doesn't work and throws the `Request was short circuited at action filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter'.` exception.

Am I missing something? Why are they doing this and how do I work with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work like I described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520927/3608449) answer, by adding `text/plain` to formats that `JsonInputFormatter` should format.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        foreach (var formatter in config.InputFormatters)
        {
            if (formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonInputFormatter))
                 ((JsonInputFormatter)formatter).SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                      MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
        }
     });
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, there's a built-in solution in Amazon SNS, which just launched support for custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the launch post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You'll have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling either the `Subscribe` or the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html

Alternatively, you can use AWS CloudFormation for setting this policy as well, using the `AWS::SNS::Subscription` resource.