# .NET Core 1.0 Web Api processing request body as JSON when content-type is text/plain

Tags: json, .net-core, content-type, asp.net-core-webapi

A vendor API I need to use is sending a POST request with content-type: text/plain and JSON in the body.

How do I parse it in .net core 1.0 web api?

I'm sure I need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234865/3608449) (code below) answer, but I don't know how in web api.

```
    public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            switch (contentType.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "text/plain":
                case "application/json":
                    return WebContentFormat.Json;
                case "application/xml":
                    return WebContentFormat.Xml;
                default:
                    return WebContentFormat.Default;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work by adding the `text/plain` content-type to the `JsonInputFormatter` in `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices()` method, like so:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                foreach (var formatter in config.InputFormatters)
                {
                    if (formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonInputFormatter))
                        ((JsonInputFormatter)formatter).SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
                }
            });
            ...
         }
```

**Edit**: I made a [seed](https://github.com/LUS1N/aws_sns_dotnetcore_httpclient) project for the SNS client lambda, that parses the message and confirms the subscription out the box.